# How to handle "Double requirement given" error when installing requirements for Odoo

Tags: python, windows-10, odoo, odoo-13

I'm trying to get started with Python and Odoo. According to [the instructions](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/setup/install.html#dependencies), I'm supposed to execute `pip install -r .\requirements.txt`, upon which I get an error.

> Ignoring gevent: markers 'sys_platform != "win32" and python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
> ERROR: Double requirement given: gevent==1.4.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 9)) (already in gevent==1.5.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 8)), name='gevent')

I do understand that the following lines are the issue, the first being omitted due to unsatisfied condition, the latter two colliding. I run Python 3.8.5 and pip 20.2.3 under Windows 10, so those conditions are fullfilled.

> gevent==1.1.2 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version < '3.7'
> gevent==1.5.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
> gevent==1.4.0 ; sys_platform == 'win32'

Being a total noob in the area, I can't even tell if it's a Python or an Odoo issue, let alone, how to trouble-shoot it. I've tried removing the lines individually, which allowed to pass that part of the installation. However, as expected, it led to some errors further on, which I don't even quote as I'm sure I'm not supposed to horse around in the default *requirements.py* file provided by people way smarter than me.

Googling didn't get me far for those specific packages, while general discussion (regarding other packages) was aligned with the conclusion that they just won't work together. Didn't made me much wiser, which likely depends on my incompetence from the area.

How can I approach the issue? And/or - what keywords are of significance when googling it further?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/setup/install.html

Odoo provides packaged installers for Windows
[image]

Comment: Does it require me to drop down to v.3.6 of Python as the other answer suggests? I'm feeling rather unsure of the whole area with Python and Odoo, coming from another tech-stack all together.

Comment: If something worked in Python3.6, it also work in Python3.8/Python3.7

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. First I remove the line

```
gevent==1.4.0 ; sys_platform == 'win32'
```

and could proceed, but few steps later I had to learn that Odoo is not ready for Python 3.8. You get issues with Pillow ...

Installing Python 3.6 solves the problem.

Comment: Me being rather nooby, I have problems estimating the significance of the environment and tooling in Python. So a few follow-ups are here. 1:Is Odoo not ready for Python 3.8 on Windows or in general? 2: How important is the Pillow-package in Python/Odoo? 3: Are there a lot of issues under Windows with Odoo in general or is Linux a wiser choice?